# How to cd in bash with partial path

Tags: bash, shell

I am new to bash. I wanted to know how can i "cd" to a partial path in a shell script.

The path i want to cd to in my script is `C:\Users\abcxyz\Documents\Projects\BD Work\Log2time\Final\Menu testing\Do_not_modify_files\All_Artifacts`
I want to cd to:

```
 cd *\Do_not_modify_files\All_Artifacts
```

if i pwd after
cd `C:/Users/abcxyz/Documents/Projects/BD Work/Log2time/Final/Menu testing/Do_not_modify_files/All_Artifacts` - i can see the files.But

if i do pwd after
cd `*/Menu testing/Do_not_modify_files/All_Artifacts
error is -  No such file or directory`

Comment: What do you think that `cd */Menu testing/Do_not_modify_files/All_Artifacts` actually means? (Hints: what does `*` expand to? Won't the space between `Menu` and `testing` separate two arguments?)

Comment: For the spacing between menu and testing,i already added double quotes. Sorry i am new to bash but how can i cd to " *\Do_not_modify_files\All_Artifacts". where * can be anything?

Comment: You can change directory into only one directory at one time... So you must decide what exactly it is which you want to do. Find one directory named `All_Artifacts` at random in your system and `cd` into it? Find them all and do something in each of them? What happens if your system doesn't actually have anywhere a directory named `All_Artifacts`?

Answer (score 0):

This worked - 
cd ./Do_not_modify_files\All_Artifacts